# Getting Jenkins to fail when Swagger-Diff returns differences

Tags: jenkins, swagger

So I have a Jenkins job I'm testing right now that is comparing two Swagger contract files [like this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore.json).

I'm using this to run my compare:

```
npx swagger-diff <url1> <url2>
```

What happens when I modify the contract on two of the endpoints I only get a warning and not an error and it wont cause Jenkins to report that the build failed. Is there anyway I can configure this to ensure that the Jenkins build will fail if there are contract differences?

The ultimate goal if this is to be able to watch an endpoint so that we know when it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving this by using the Jenkins plugin [Log Parser](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) to read through the log and look for specific breaking changes that we determined would be "fatal".